# Get week number according to your locale in Zend_Date

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to get the current week number with Zend Framework.

In France, weeks are defined like this :

- A week begins on Monday (whereas weeks begin on Sunday in the US).
- The first week of the year is the week which contains the 4th of January.

In 2014, the first week begins January 1st. But if I use in Zend Framework 1.12 for this date like $zend_date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK) it returns 53 (and not 1). and for January 12th, it returns 1 (and not 2)

How can I correct that ? I already tried to change the locale to fr-fr but it didn't work.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to replicate your problem doing

```
$date1 = new Zend_Date('2014-01-01');
$date2 = new Zend_Date('2014-01-12');

$date1->get(Zend_Date::WEEK) // gives 01
$date2->get(Zend_Date::WEEK) // gives 02
```

Also tried passing 'fr' as locale. It gives the correct answer.

I am not sure if it's a `Zend` issue.

Try the PHP solution:

```
php > echo date('W',strtotime('2014-01-01'));
01
php > echo date('W',strtotime('2014-01-12'));
02
```

Comment: my dear. you are right .. i had a php function for this result and the fault was the javascript version. thanks for your help and sorry to bother you. regards